# How to persist objects and its nested objects at once?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm with some problems trying to persist an object and its items, here're my classes:

```
@Entity(name = "Contract")
@Table(name = "contract")
public class Contract implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idContract", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ContractItem> contractItem;

    //getters & setters...
}
```

.

```
@Entity(name = "ContractItem")
@Table( name = "contract_item")
public class ContractItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_contract")
    private Long idContract;

    //getters & setters...
}
```

I'm extending `JpaRepository` im my repositories and using `.save(contract)` to persist but every time my application only persists the contract not de items, I've already tried `CascadeType.ALL`, `MERGE` and `PERSIST` in which either the result is the same, or I get an exception that my idContract must not be null.

Need some help here guys, thanks in advance !

Comment: You can check a bidirectional one-to-many example in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional)...

Comment: For any entry in `Contract ` with  some `id`, do you want the same `id` to be given to each individual `idContract` in the list `List<ContractItem> contractItem;`